# How are injections, surjections and bijections described for functions with an ordered pair as an argument?

Tags: graph-theory

When given a function with an ordered pair as argument i.e.

Z × Z → Z given by f(m, n) = m − n − 1

How should injections, surjections and bijections be described?
Should there be a domain of tuples ie. (1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (2,2)? Or possibly an extra domain or codomain?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you perhaps extend your question with some more concrete examples of what it is that confuses you? For example give an example of a function where you're not sure whether it is injective (or surjective), _together with_ an explanation of how you think both answers might make sense depending on how you understand the definitions?

Comment: A function from $A$ to $B$ is e.g. injective if for all $x,y \in A$ we have $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$. The same definition applies whether $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to B$ or whatever $A$ is, as user3482749 points out. What about this confuses you?

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't functions with multiple arguments. Those are functions taking a single argument in the domain $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. The definitions are exactly as for any other function.

Comment: Aren't 'm' and 'n' separate arguments to the function? How are injections, surjections and bijections described for this?

Comment: @user604574 Describing two separate arguments $m,n$ is the same as describing a single argument which is an ordered pair: $(m,n)$.

Comment: How would injections, surjections and bijections described for this?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, please remove so that someone can provide help with this topic

Comment: This absolutely is an answer to the question: the definitions are precisely the standard ones, with no changes whatsoever, because the definitions do not specify anything about the domain and codomain other than that they are sets.

Comment: @user604574 Anyone can still submit answers—best just to let them do so and then accept the one that helps by clicking the tick next to it. If other people think this isn't an answer they'll downvote it.